# Configuring Spring to ignore dependencies annotated with @Inject

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

I have an EJB class in which I need to inject two beans - one should be injected by the EJB container and other is a Spring Container.

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
@LocalBean
public class SomeClass {

    @Inject
    private EJBClass a;

    @Autowired
    private SpringComponent b;

}
```

Here, the Spring interceptor trying to intercept the injection of bean 'a' and it's getting failed. I want the EJB container to inject the bean 'a' and Spring container to inject bean 'b'.

Please show me a way out here.

Comment: If you're using Spring 3.0+, why don't you just use `@Inject` instead of `@Autowired`? See also a.o. [this Mkyong article](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-and-jsr-330-inject-and-named-example/).

Comment: You can try Spring's `exclude-filter`: `<context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="javax.inject.Inject"/>`. I'm not confident if it'll detect that annotation at the field level, but the documentation says it'll work with the type level that the annotation presents. It's worth a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By customizing the `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` class, dependencies annotated with `@Inject` can be excluded from auto wiring.

To understand what happens behind the scene, have a look at source code of 
**SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java** -

```
/**
 * Actually autowire the target bean after construction/passivation.
 * @param target the target bean to autowire
 */
protected void doAutowireBean(Object target) {
    AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bpp = new AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    configureBeanPostProcessor(bpp, target);
    bpp.setBeanFactory(getBeanFactory(target));
    bpp.processInjection(target);
}
```

At first line, of `doAutowireBean`, a new instance of `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is created. Here set of annotations to be scanned for auto wiring dependencies are configured.

```
/**
 * Create a new AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
 * for Spring's standard {@link Autowired} annotation.
 * <p>Also supports JSR-330's {@link javax.inject.Inject} annotation, if available.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add(Autowired.class);
    this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add(Value.class);
    try {
        this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add((Class<? extends Annotation>)
                ClassUtils.forName("javax.inject.Inject", AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class.getClassLoader()));
        logger.info("JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // JSR-330 API not available - simply skip.
    }
}
```

Since, by default, the `@Inject` annotation is configured spring scans respective dependencies marked with `@Inject` and tries to auto wire them.

To exclude `@Inject` annotated dependencies write below custom class.

```
public class CustomSpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor extends SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor {

    /**
     * Template method for configuring the
     * {@link AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor} used for autowiring.
     * @param processor the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to configure
     * @param target the target bean to autowire with this processor
     */
    protected void configureBeanPostProcessor(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor processor, Object target) {
        Set<Class> annotationsToScan = new HashSet<Class>();
        annotationsToScan.add(Autowired.class);
        annotationsToScan.add(Value.class);
        processor.setAutowiredAnnotationTypes(annotationsToScan);

    }
}
```

Here `configureBeanPostProcessor` hook is utilized to customize the bean post processor so as to include only those annotations which we require to be auto wired.

After applying this custom class as interceptor in code the desired behaviour can be achieved

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(CustomSpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
@LocalBean
public class SomeClass {

@Inject
private EJBClass a;

@Autowired
private SpringComponent b;

}
```

Let know in comments if you face any issues. Also feel free to optimize the code as deemed fit and excuse any compilations / formatting issues.

Comment: were you able to achieve desired behavior ?

Comment: Would you have a solution for Spring 5? The SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor does not exist anymore. Maybe you can see also my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582720/spring-bean-implemented-by-a-3rd-party-library-that-uses-inject-conflicting-wit?noredirect=1#comment105333688_59582720 where, in a bit different context, I managed with a different solution, but somehow I feel that this is an insufficiency in Spring and should be addressed by their developers.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) it seems that the class is still available. Is there any compilation / runtime error encountered when tried using this ?

Answer (score -1):

Use `@EJB` annotation to inject EJB