# Spring Bean implemented by a 3rd party library that uses @Inject conflicting with Spring's injection mechanism

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, owl-api

I am trying to have a `@Bean` implemented by a class from a 3rd party library (OWL API).

This implementation uses an `@Inject` annotation. Spring tries to interpret it, interfering with the injection mechanism of the 3rd party library and avoiding it to work as intended.

**Is there a way to instruct Spring to ignore the `@Inject` annotations of the bean implementation, when instantiating the bean?**

I found few questions about this subject but none of them provided a solution usable in my context.

I actually managed to resolve the issue myself, by wrapping the 3rd party object in an anonymous class, apparently creating a barrier for Spring and preventing it to look into this object (see the point 3. below), but I consider it to be an ugly workaround.

**Details:**

According to the OWL API documentation, the `OWLOntologyManager` is to be created like this:

```
OWLOntologyManagerFactory ontologyManagerFactory = new OWLManager();
OWLOntologyManager owlOntologyManager = ontologyManagerFactory.get();
//... use owlOntologyManager
```

Indeed, in my Spring application that was working. However, I need to have the `OWLOntologyManagerFactory` with an `application` scope and `OWLOntologyManager` with a `Session` scope.

So I declared each of these two objects as a Spring `@Bean`, with an appropriate scope and started to receive an error:

> *Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.sessionOWLOntologyManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setIRIMappers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}*

See below samples of the code.

1. Functional first test of the code, not meeting the application needs:

```
@RestController
public class OntologiesController {
    @RequestMapping("ontologies")
    public String manager_loadOntology(
        @RequestParam(value="ontologyIriString") String ontologyIriString
    ) throws OWLOntologyCreationException
    {
        OWLOntologyManagerFactory ontologyManagerFactory = new OWLManager();
        OWLOntologyManager owlOntologyManager = ontologyManagerFactory.get();
        OWLOntology ontology = owlOntologyManager.loadOntology(IRI.create(ontologyIriString));
        return ontology.toString();
    }
}
```

2. Not functional code failing to create OWLOntologyManager with the error quoted above.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationScopeConfig {
    @Bean
    @ApplicationScope
    public OWLOntologyManagerFactory applicationOWLOntologyManagerFactory() {
        return new OWLManager();
    }
}
@Configuration
public class SessionScopeConfig {
    @Autowired
    OWLOntologyManagerFactory applicationOWLOntologyManagerFactory;
    @Bean
    @SessionScope
    public OWLOntologyManager sessionOWLOntologyManager() {
        return applicationOWLOntologyManagerFactory.get();
    }
}
@RestController
public class OntologiesController {
    @Autowired
    private OWLOntologyManager sessionOWLOntologyManager;
    @RequestMapping("ontologies")
    public String manager_loadOntology(
            @RequestParam(value="ontologyIriString") String ontologyIriString
    ) throws OWLOntologyCreationException
    {
        OWLOntology ontology = sessionOWLOntologyManager.loadOntology(IRI.create(ontologyIriString));
        return ontology.toString();
    }
}
```

3. Functional code, working as needed, but ugly, is there a way to improve it?

In the code from the point 2 I modified the sessionOWLOntologyManager() as follows, wrapping it to an anonymous class that prevents Spring to look into the real owlOntologyManager.

```
@Bean
@SessionScope
public OWLOntologyManager sessionOWLOntologyManager() {
    final OWLOntologyManager owlOntologyManager = applicationOWLOntologyManagerFactory.get();
    return new OWLOntologyManager() {
        public void clearOntologies() {
            owlOntologyManager.clearOntologies();
        }
        //additional 400 lines implementing all methods by delegating to owlOntologyManager
        //Apparently that creates a barrier for Spring so it does not conflict with the
        //@Inject annotation in the implementation of the original owlOntologyManager,
        //but in spite of having IDE support to generate this delegation, I consider it
        //as an workaround.
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592743/configuring-spring-to-ignore-dependencies-annotated-with-inject

Comment: I saw that already. They replace SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor with a custom implementation, but in my project that class does not exist. So apparently, in my type of project (nothing with EJB, rather REST service), Spring uses a different mechanism for the autowiring. Or maybe it is a difference in the Spring version - I use the latest 2.2.2.

Comment: There must be a class in Spring that you can override to exclude the @Inject annotation.   :-)

Comment: Right, actually, after the second look, I found the org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor that they refer to as well. Yes, so I assume that eventually I could use the approach that they use too.

Comment: If you do, can you post your solution?

Comment: If it helps at all, `OWLManager` has static methods to create managers - so your session scoped method could just call `OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager()`.

Comment: The error you've seen should not arise from any of the calls to `OWLManager`, though - to me it seems that Spring is trying to create an instance of `OWLOntologyManagerImpl` without using `OWLManager` (ultimately, the problem is that the dependencies it needs to resolve are not Spring components, they're provided via ServiceLoader style files in `META-INF/services`).

Comment: Thanks to point out the method. The result is however the same. When I see the implementation of this `OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager`, so it is: `return normalInjector.inject(normalInjector.getImplementation(OWLOntologyManager.class));`, i.e. the OWL API obviously uses its own injection mechanism (based on @Inject, as I found on the setters of the objects that I get the error about) and Spring conflicts with that (tries to do the injections again). Well, I found a way how to block it by wrapping the object, but I would imagine to have a Spring annotation for that...

Answer (score 0):

As it eventually turns out that this is related to [Configuring Spring to ignore dependencies annotated with @Inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592743/configuring-spring-to-ignore-dependencies-annotated-with-inject), so I assume that a chance to get better answers is low and I post my additional findings in a reply to myself.

1. The class responsible for recognizing the @Inject is org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. With my Spring knowledge I was however not able to intercept its behavior. The class SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor, mentioned in the related question, does not exist in Spring 5.
2. For now I go with an improvement to my solution in the point 3. Instead of generating dozens of delegating methods (it can be done automatically by IDE), I go with the code below, using the reflection. The advantage is that it will be more resistant to changes if I should upgrade the OWLAPI library one day. Also it has significantly less lines. I assume that the reflection might be less performant.

```
@Bean
@SessionScope
public OWLOntologyManager sessionOWLOntologyManager() {

    final OWLOntologyManager owlOntologyManager = applicationOWLOntologyManagerFactory.get();

    //Instead of returning owlOntologyManager directly,
    //the delegating proxy prevents Spring to resolve @Inject annotations
    //in the implementation of owlOntologyManager.

    return (OWLOntologyManager)Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            owlOntologyManager.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            owlOntologyManager.getClass().getInterfaces(),
            (o, method, args) ->
                method.invoke(owlOntologyManager, args)
        );
}
```